# Unable to start BI services in OBIEE 11g

Tags: oracle11g, obiee

I would like to see for your help in my issue when starting BI Services. The cmd window gets stuck on below log and I have no idea what to do next.

I would be glad for any help that you can extend to me.

```
<Oct 21, 2013 3:25:08 AM GMT-06:00> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling CryptoJ JCE        Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true>
<Oct 21, 2013 3:25:08 AM GMT-06:00> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true>
<Oct 21, 2013 3:25:08 AM GMT-06:00> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Version 20.10-b01 from Sun Microsystems Inc.>
<Oct 21, 2013 3:25:09 AM GMT-06:00> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 10.3.5.0  Fri Apr 1 20:20:06 PDT 2011 1398638 >
<Oct 21, 2013 3:25:12 AM GMT-06:00> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING>
<Oct 21, 2013 3:25:12 AM GMT-06:00> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool>
<Oct 21, 2013 3:25:12 AM GMT-06:00> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file D:\OBIEE\user_projects\domains\bifoundation_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.>
```

Comment: You will have to check the AdminServer log to find out the issue. In the Enterprise Manager, which all services did not start?

Comment: My issue got resolved. The rootcause was the ldap files being corrupted. I replaced it with my old one and resetup all users and it worked:)

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you using?

You need to verify the AdminServer log to find out which process is not running. See path-D:\OBIEE\user_projects\domains\bifoundation_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log.

Also, you can check the BI services in command prompt OPMNCTL STATUS to see which service is down then check the respective logs files for the services that are down.